# How to handle multiple checkout flows in Google Enhanced Ecommerce funnels?

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I'm setting up Enhanced Ecommerce for Analytics, and I'm trying to figure out the right way to represent my checkout flow in terms of the checkout funnel, given that there are several different possible flows depending on how the customer wants to pay.

Step 1: Open the cart. So far so good.

Step 2: Select payment method.

Step 3: Now I'm unsure. If the payment method in step 2 was "Credit Card", the next step is a form where the customer enters all their credit card and shipping info, which should probably break down into several steps. But if the payment method was "PayPal", they're whisked off to the PayPal site to authorize payment, then back to me to review their info and commit the order.

Customers who selected PayPal never see the Credit Card form (and never complete any of those steps), and customers who select Credit Card never see the PayPal review form. So numbering the steps linearly (ie. the credit card form is steps 3-4-5 and the PayPal return form is step 6) doesn't make sense.

I can send the payment type to Google as a "checkout option", but that doesn't seem to solve the issue of numbering the checkout steps.

I can't find any information about multiple checkout flows in the [Enhanced Ecommerce documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=en). What is the standard way to handle this?