# How to properly track multiple checkout flows in Google Enhanced Ecommerce?

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to setup the checkout steps feature in Google Enahanced Ecommerce through Google Tag Manager. One issue I currently have is that the [official doc](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce) has no mention on what if my checkout process has slight variations and there is more than one route checking out.

For example:

If user isn't logged in, the checkout flow is something like this:

1. /checkout/cart
2. /checkout/signin
3. /checkout/billing
4. /checkout/payment
5. /checkout/confirmation

For logged in user, it will skip step 2.

Someone asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618755/how-to-handle-multiple-checkout-flows-in-google-enhanced-ecommerce-funnels) a year ago and got no reply. So would love to get some insights/suggestions on this topic.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there _is_ a good answer - use multiple views each with a with different checkout configuration, or buy Google Analytics 360 which has custom funnel reports as additional report type in the custom reports.

Answer (score 1):

I would fire step 2 on step 3.

For step 2 (regardless of page), I would also include a checkout option based on logged-in status.

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'checkoutOption',
    'ecommerce': {
      'checkout_option': {
        'actionField': {'step': 2, 'option': ["loggedIn"|"signIn"|"signUp"|"guest"]}
      }
    }
  });
```

So if a user is logged-in when they are redirected to the billing page, checkout step 2 and step 3 fires, as well as the checkout option "loggedIn" fired for step 2.

When reviewing the enhanced ecommerce checkout report, you can create segments based on the logged-in status.

Similar to how you could apply "View Cart" in this photo:
[image: ecommerce checkout]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It looks like GTM doesn't allow you to push multiple steps (fire step 2 on step 3) on the same page as values will be overridden by the latter request and I did a brief test it seems to be the case. I am now trying to play around with the step numbers like if already signed in, /billing would be step 2. Otherwise step 3 to see if that works. Perhaps I can add current login status in the checkout option.

Comment: Whilst you are unable to send multiple steps on the same page, you can set the field 'page' for the logged-in users (e.g. /login/auto). This will allow you to have both step 2 and step 3 fire on the same physical page by changing the page value being sent to Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to leave the cart and sign in steps out of the checkout process. I’ve seen many guides including these steps in the checkout funnel, but I think they should not be there.